# Export HTML table to Excel with Excel formulas

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I had successfully exported excel from HTML table using function mentioned below

```
  handleExportExcelButton :function(){
    var self = this;
    $(".monthly-booking-sheets-report-details #bookingSheetsExcelReportButton").unbind('click');
    $(".monthly-booking-sheets-report-details #bookingSheetsExcelReportButton").click(function(e){
      var monthly_booking_sheets_report_table = document.getElementById('monthlyBookingSheetsReportTable');
      var monthly_booking_report_table_html = "<table border='2px'>";
      for(index = 0 ; index < monthly_booking_sheets_report_table.rows.length-1 ; index++)
      {
        monthly_booking_report_table_html += monthly_booking_sheets_report_table.rows[index].innerHTML+"</tr>";
      }
      monthly_booking_report_table_html += "</table>";
      var anchor_html_excel = document.createElement('a');
      anchor_html_excel.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel' + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(monthly_booking_report_table_html);
      anchor_html_excel.download = 'Booking Report ' + self.start_date + '_' + self.end_date + '.xls';
      anchor_html_excel.click();
      e.preventDefault();
    })
  }
```

And before exporting I am applying some calculation from javascript in HTML table column for example `C = A - B`

```
  A  |   B  | C
=================
1200 | 1000 | 200
1000 | 500  | 500
```

which also I achieved. **Now I want to export excel with this formula so, if in case if anyone edits either column A or B values in excel then column C should show the new difference between respective values. So what changes I need to make in my javascript function to make this work**

> NOTE: In actual table, I have 20 columns in my HTML table